# Magento 1.7 Paypal goes to old address

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7

We've recently changed the Pay Pal account associated with our business,  so I have changed the Pay Pal address for accepting Pay Pal payments in Magento.  The settings save successfully and hold true when revisiting the Pay Pal configuration page in the Magento admin.  However, for some reason when you choose Pay Pal as the payment option, it is still going to the old email address's Pay Pal account.

I have completely flushed the cache several times, re-indexed and even searched the entire database for the old Pay Pal email address and it is not present.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the problem - Express Checkout was active, so the PayPal email address is completely ignored and instead the API credentials are used, which for this particular store view were for the old account.

Hope this helps someone else as daft as me!